# Can we call the processes and rules required to get an official permit "red tape"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Can we call the processes and rules required to get an official permit "red tape"?

I want to know that.

Comment: You mean "red tape", of course?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase *red tape* does indeed mean all the processes and rules involved; but it is usually employed specifically to characterize the processes and rules as complicated and burdensome.

> It's appalling how much red tape the DOT puts you through to get a bicycle permit.

If the process is straightforward and easy, or if you're not concerned with how easy or difficult it is, use another expression.

> To get a bicycle permit you must follow the procedures laid down by the DOT.
>   Getting a bicycle permit's easy: just fill out a form, pay your $15, and get it stamped. No red tape at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  From Wiktionary:

> ...
>   2. (*idiomatic*) Time-consuming regulations or bureaucratic procedures.  All the **red tape** and paperwork that goes on there prevents any
>   progress.